# how to change the size of the drag and drop of antd Upload?

Tags: upload, antd

I use Antd to upload pictures. I don't know how to update the style of the [Upload component](https://ant.design/components/upload)

I want to change the width and size of the drag and drop box but I don't see the option.

[Here is the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/g5p3ks?file=/demo.tsx)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:
You can directly modify ant-upload css class, but this will override every upload component you have:

```
// css file
.ant-upload {
  // don't forget to add !important or
  // antd will override your styles
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

Or you can assign a custom css class to your upload component and then modify only ant-upload wich is child of your custom class:

```
<Upload
  ... other props
  className={"customSizedUpload"}
>
  { .... }
</Upload>

// css file
.customSizedUpload .ant-upload {
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am talking about the <Upload /> element. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/g5p3ks?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have one question. When the image is downloaded and previewed, it is always the same size (quite small), I would like to make it the same size as the Upload box, do you know how to do that ?

Comment: are you talking about these 4 image previews in upload listing, right? In this case you can use `itemRender` prop. I've made a quick working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pictures-wall-antd-5-8-6-forked-vndt66?file=/demo.tsx). You'll just need to adjust styles.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answers and patience is grealty appreciated.